# Memory leak in CFAttributedStringRef

Tags: iphone, objective-c, pdf, memory, memory-leaks

I use the following method to draw text on a PDF document (context).
Somehow instruments comes up with the following line leaking

```
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
```

Where i am release the stringRef. Here's the code (After the correct answers here's the updated/working code):

```
- (void)drawText:(NSString*)textToDraw inFrame:(CGRect)frameRect{

CFStringRef stringRef = (__bridge CFStringRef)textToDraw;
// Prepare the text using a Core Text Framesetter
CFAttributedStringRef currentText = CFAttributedStringCreate(NULL, stringRef, NULL);
CTFramesetterRef framesetter = CTFramesetterCreateWithAttributedString(currentText);

CGMutablePathRef framePath = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathAddRect(framePath, NULL, frameRect);

// Get the frame that will do the rendering.
CFRange currentRange = CFRangeMake(0, 0);
CTFrameRef frameRef = CTFramesetterCreateFrame(framesetter, currentRange, framePath, NULL);
CGPathRelease(framePath);

// Get the graphics context.
CGContextRef    currentContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

// Put the text matrix into a known state. This ensures
// that no old scaling factors are left in place.
CGContextSetTextMatrix(currentContext, CGAffineTransformIdentity);

// Core Text draws from the bottom-left corner up, so flip
// the current transform prior to drawing.
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, frameRect.origin.y*2);
CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);

// Draw the frame.
CTFrameDraw(frameRef, currentContext);

CGContextScaleCTM(currentContext, 1.0, -1.0);
CGContextTranslateCTM(currentContext, 0, (-1)*frameRect.origin.y*2);

CFRelease(frameRef);
//CFRelease(stringRef); The string shouldn't be released
CFRelease(framesetter);
//Added the next line:
CFRelease(currentText);
```

}

Tested it on a device as the simulator; it leaks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to release the CFAttributedStringRef as well and I don't see that you've released it in the method.  Ownership in this function follows the create rule

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFMemoryMgmt/Concepts/Ownership.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001148-103029

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. When i'm adding CFRelease(currentText) my app crashes.. mmm

Comment: can you post the error?  It's likely you are it when it's being accessed by something else (like framesetter, for example).

Comment: it just crashes, but when i have NSZombies enabled it comes up with: *** -[CFString release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xf6534c0

Comment: is the crash in the method?  And you seem to be releasing stringRef which is not under your control (you used the bridge to it,  not copy or create).

Comment: the crash is outside of the method, im not sure where it goes wrong, but i think i have to check the whole class i wrote. Thanks for the quick reply!

Comment: I found it! Like you said; add CFRelease(currentText); besides that i had to delete CFRelease(stringRef);